# using json_encode to pass variables into js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have a `.php` that has a query, once the query has executed I am trying to pass the data to a `.js` file then use the ID's within some other `.html` file

**Problem**

I cant get the javascrip ID's to print out in the html file, I have checked the data base where the query writes to and its getting the data so the varible php side is valid.

**Part of my .php query**

```
 $stmt->execute();
    $stmtp->execute();

    echo json_encode(array('percentile' => $percentile, 'suffix' => $suffix, 'timesTaken' => $timesTaken));
```

**part of my .js file**

```
    $("#next-button")
        .click(function() {
            a.eventHub.publish("ui/nextclick")
        }), this.showView("test")
}, UI.prototype.updatePercentile = function(a) {
    if (this.isStandalone || -1 == a.percentile) $("#results-percentages")
        .hide();
    else {
        $("#results-percentages")
            .show(), $("#results-percentile-1")
            .html(a.percentile), $("#results-suffix")
            .html(a.suffix), $("#results-suffix-2")
            .html(a.suffix), 1 === a.timesTaken ? ($("#results-timestaken")
                .html(a.timesTaken + " time"), $("#results-percentile-2")
                .html("100")) : ($("#results-timestaken")
                .html(a.timesTaken + " times"), $("#results-percentile-2")
                .html(a.percentile));
        var b = 0;
        $("#percentile-scale .scale-item")
            .each(function() {
                b += $(this)
                    .outerWidth()
            }), $("#percentile-scale .scale-indicator")
            .css("left", b * a.percentile / 100 + 10 + "px")
    }
```

**and my .html file**

```
<div id="results-percentages">
                        <p class="scale-text">
                            your <span id="percentile"></span><span id="results-suffix"></span> percentile. <br>more text <span id="results-timestaken"></span> 
                            more<span id="results-percentile-2"></span>% 
                        </p>
</div
```

Comment: Personally, the formatting of your code could do with work. Why are you using the `,` operator to split up multiple statements? Don't use ternary operator instead of an `if-else` clause to cause side effects.

Comment: thanks for your input, ill work on my code format later